# How to use Axios/Vue.js to call data from SQLite/Django backend?

Tags: python, django, vue.js, axios

**Status Quo:**

Whenever a user visits my web application, Axios makes a request to a third party API to fetch data and populate the frontend with that data using `v-for`.

Conclusion: I have one API call per website visitor.

**Desired status:**

Whenever a user visits my web application, Axios shall **fetch the data from the SQLite database** which itself is populated every XX seconds by a python `request` to reduce API calls.

**Questions:**

Now I implemented a SQLite database using Django `models` and `views`. So far so good, the API gets fetched regularly and updates the database table properly.

**1.)** How can I now call the data in the database using Axios? As by my research Axios somehow needs to call a `view` and the `view` will call the data from the database, is this correct?

**2.)** If Axios needs to call a `view`, do I need another `view.py` file that calls the database? If I would insert the needed `view` function into the existing `view.py` file it would initiate another API call, wouldn't it?

**3.)** And how can I implement the link to the `view` function to Axios? Instead of a third party API url would I just use the path to the `view` file?

**Quotes_app/Views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from Quotes_app.models import ratesEUR

import json
import requests

response = requests.get("http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=XXXX&base=EUR")

rates_EUR = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
timestamp = rates_EUR['timestamp']
base = rates_EUR['base']
date = rates_EUR['date']
rates = rates_EUR['rates']
id = 1

rates_new = ratesEUR(id=id, timestamp=timestamp, base=base, date=date, rates=rates)
rates_new.save()


def render_Quotes_app(request, template="Quotes_app/templates/Quotes_app/Quotes_app.html"):
    return render(request, template)
```

**Quotes_app/models.py:**

```
from django.db import models


class ratesEUR(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    base = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    rates = models.CharField(max_length=8)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.base
```

**Vue.js/axios: (as of now directly fetching the API)**

```
Vue.config.devtools = true;

var app = new Vue({
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  el: '.eurQuotesWrapper',
  data() {
    return {
      rates: [],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    rates1() {
      const ratesArr1 = Object.entries(this.rates);
      const ret = ratesArr1.reduce((a, c, i, d) => {
        if (i < d.length / 2) a[c[0]] = c[1];
        return a;
      }, {});
      console.log('rates1', ret);
      return ret;
    },
    rates2() {
      const ratesArr2 = Object.entries(this.rates);
      const ret = ratesArr2.reduce((a, c, i, d) => {
        if (i >= d.length / 2) a[c[0]] = c[1];
        return a;
      }, {});
      console.log('rates2', ret);
      return ret;
    }
  },
  created() {
    axios
      .get("http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=XXXX&base=EUR")
      .then(response => {
        this.rates = response.data.rates;
        console.log(this.rates);
        for(key in this.rates) {
          this.rates[key] = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
            minimumFractionDigits: 5,
            maximumFractionDigits: 5
          }).format(this.rates[key]);
        }
        console.log(this.rates);
      });
    }
});
```

**In advance thank you very much for your help!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use DRF(Django Rest Framework) to make REST API's** or You can use `JsonResponse`
to send JSON objects as response.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse



data = # Your data
JsonResponse(data, encoder=MyJSONEncoder)
```

[For more details visit django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/)

### Better would be if you use DRF for making rest apis. It's much easier.